# Read YAML configuration file in Python

Tags: python, pyyaml

I am trying to read a YAML configuration file and display it to the terminal. Now I want to try something like checking if the database (db) in the YAML file is not Sqlite or Postgres then exception will raise but I don't know how. I tried but failed, what am I doing wrong?

My `test.yaml` file :

```
database: 

dbopt:
   host: bvcbvcbvcb.com
   port: 5432
   dbname: db1
   user: username
   password: 1234
   client_encoding: utf-8
   connect_timeout: 60
   sslmode: none

query:
   select * from manufacturing_product
```

My code:

```
# process_yaml.py file`
import yaml

with open(r'D:\Python\test.yaml') as file:
    # The FullLoader parameter handles the conversion from YAML
    # scalar values to Python the dictionary format
    data = yaml.full_load(file)

    for item, doc in data.items():
        print(item, ":", doc)

    def __init__(self, dbconf):
        self._dbconf = dict(dbconf)

        # checking for database type
        dbtype = self.get_db_type()
        if dbtype != 'sqlite' and dbtype != 'postgres':
            raise exceptions.InvalidConfigError(
                'E01001', 'Invalid database type, should be sqlite or postgres.')
        else:
            self.dbtype = dbtype
```

My program still cannot catch the exception. My terminal :

```
database: 

dbopt:
   host: 
   port: 5432
   dbname: db1
   user: username
   password: 1234
   client_encoding: utf-8
   connect_timeout: 60
   sslmode: none

query:
   select * from manufacturing_product
```

Comment: You don't know how to do _what_? What happens instead? If an error occurs, please add what it says to your question.

Comment: @martineau Sorry, maybe I write unclearly. No errors occurred, I successfully print the data in the file to the terminal. I mean when changing the db item data in the above file which is not sqlite or postgre, an exception will occur ```Invalid database type, should be sqlite or postgres.```. I wrote it but still couldn't catch the exception. Can you help me ? Let me edit it

Comment: Sorry, I still don't quite understand. Regardless, the way to **catch** exceptions in Python is by using a combination of [`try`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#try) statements in conjunction with one or more `except` clauses — and you have neither in the code in your question (looks like it could **raise** one, though).

Comment: Something else: I noticed that you're defining what looks like a class `__init__()` method that's not part of any [class definition](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-first-look-at-classes) and instead is just kind of out in the middle of nowhere. This makes no sense. I think you may need to find and read a good Python tutorial that covers the creation of classes assuming that's what you're (also) are trying to do. Note however I **do not** think that's what you are asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several pieces missing from your code, and your function `__init__` is never called. You probably copied it from some example with a class, that also had a method `get_db_type()`.

```
class InvalidConfigError(Exception):
    pass

class DB:
    def __init__(self, dbconf):
        self._dbconf = dict(dbconf)

        # checking for database type
        dbtype = self.get_db_type()
        if dbtype != 'sqlite' and dbtype != 'postgres':
            raise InvalidConfigError(
                'E01001', 'Invalid database type, should be sqlite or postgres.')
        else:
            self.dbtype = dbtype

    def get_db_type(self):
        return self._dbconf['db']


with open('test.yaml') as file:
    data = yaml.full_load(file)

    for item, doc in data.items():
        print(item, ":", doc)


    db = DB(data)
```

Which prints:

```
db : mysql
dbopt : {'host': 'bvcbvcbvcb.com', 'port': 5432, 'dbname': 'db1', 'user': 'username', 'password': '1234', 'client_encoding': 'utf-8', 'connect_timeout': 60, 'sslmode': 'none'}
query : select * from manufacturing_product
```

and then gives:

> **init**
>       raise InvalidConfigError(
>   **main**.InvalidConfigError: ('E01001', 'Invalid database type, should be sqlite or postgres.')
>   process error Command '['ryd', '--force', 'so-60160957.ryd']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

The comment

```
# The FullLoader parameter handles the conversion from YAML
# scalar values to Python the dictionary format
```

is rather of the mark. The FullLoader parses the YAML and tries to instantiate all nodes into Python objects: YAML mapping to dict, YAML sequence to list, and YAML nodes that are scalars to Python types (string, integer, float, bool, etc.)

Comment: Dear Anthon, I would like to ask for your help. Can you edit the configuration content ? Like ```host: None
   port: 6311
   dbname: spam_eggs
   user: hamburger
   password: example_password
   client_encoding: utf-8
   connect_timeout: 60
   sslmode: none ```
I have some personal information that I don't want to show. Can you help me? Please

Comment: @BinhDuong I never noticed that is your concern. Don't put in edit suggestions that has a format that doesn't reflect the actual output of the program. Since there is edit history, you can still see your information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60160957/revisions) you should at least change your passwords. And ask a moderator to collapse the history of your Q and my A